# Removing extra characters in ascii output of a data.frame using ascii library in R

Tags: r, formatting

I like to use ascii output of my results.

There is always an extra 'h' in the header of my table which I and up removing manually.

I can not not figure out how to fix it in my code. See the code and result. E.g., how many cars have how many cilinders.

```
data(mtcars)
library(ascii)
ascii(as.data.frame(table(mtcars$cyl)),include.rownames=F,format='nice')


|================ 
h| Var1 h| Freq 
| 4    | 11   
| 6    | 7    
| 8    | 14   
|================
```

I would like to remove the extra h characters from the header. so that the output looks like this:

```
|================ 
| Var1 | Freq 
| 4    | 11   
| 6    | 7    
| 8    | 14   
|================
```

Is it a bug in ascii library or in my code?
I want to do it via correct params of the ascii call rather then post processing the output, but would consider any "fix" if the proper solution is not possible.

Comment: I can't get it to produce the exact output without the h - but if you play around with storing your call to ascii into an object say `tab <- ascii(your_stuff)` then `print(tab, type = "org")` gives you something.  I can't find the full list of types and I stumbled upon that in the examples for ascii.

Comment: From the documentation for `ascii` it looks like `ascii(table(etc...))` should be sufficient.  Have you tried that, in case it's `as.data.frame` which is sending some control character to `ascii` which is being misinterpreted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not entirely obvious but the `ascii.data.frame` function takes a `header` argument that when set to FALSE will eliminate the undesired "h"s. There's also an `include.colnames` argument, should one want to get rid of what I would have called the "header".

```
> ascii(as.data.frame(table(mtcars$cyl)),include.rownames=F,header=FALSE,format='nice')
|============== 
| Var1 | Freq 
| 4    | 11   
| 6    | 7    
| 8    | 14   
|==============
```